# Simple Ajax Post in laravel 5 not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Im using a very simple form to send ajax post request but its showing a `500 (internal server error)` in the console and when i click that link it opens a file and shows error is in this line

```
// Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

The page which sends the request is `demotest.blade.php`

The URL that receives the request is `ajaxpage`, it forwards it to `AjaxController@postData`

Here is my web.php file

```
Route::get('/demotest', function(){
    return view('admin/posts/demotest');
});

Route::post('/ajaxpage', 'AjaxController@postData');
```

Here is my `demotest.blade.php` file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <form id="myform" method="POST" action="{{ url('/ajaxpage') }}">
            {!! csrf_field() !!}

            <input id="token_field" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

        <div id="display_here"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('jscript')

<script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {

        // for csrf protection when using ajax
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var firstname = $("#firstname").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajaxpage",
                data:{
                    firstname: firstname,
                    _token: $('#token_field').val()
                  },
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#display_here').html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>

@endsection
```

It consist of a single field and submit button and jquery for sending ajax request

Here is the controller which handles the request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function postData(Request $request)
    {
        return Response()->json($request::all());
    }
}
```

This is it. Still im getting an error. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up network inspector and check XHR requests you will see an error response, because you are calling method `all()` static over an array that contains the request attributes.

So to fix your error instead of

```
return Response()->json($request::all());
```

do

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

or just for a sanity check do:

```
return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
```

so when you open up console on your browser you should have the response.

Comment: It was working on the demo project after correcting but after copying the files as it is in my working project then its not working now. its showing the same error 500 (internal server error)

Comment: php artisan config:clear and php artisan route:clear. Should work the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$request` as an array or object of form attributes. Using multiple csrf_token in a form is not necessary. A single random unguessable token per session is sufficient.